# Getting child product of configurable in Observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, configurable-product

Magento 2.4.6

I am listening to the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. In my observer I am trying to get an attribute from the added child product. I did not manage so far, all data that I get is from the configurable, but not from the added simple / child product.

In my observer I have:

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
```

Now, when I do something like `$item->getId()`, I am always getting the configurable id, not the id of the child which was added. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get child product data for configurable products within the **"checkout_cart_product_add_after"** event, you can use the following approach.

**Firstly create the events.xml file in your module**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="vendor_module_custom_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

After then create an Observer and then add the following code in it.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
class CustomObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $cart;
    protected $redirect;
    protected $request;
    protected $product;
    protected $configurableproduct;
    public function __construct(RedirectInterface $redirect, Cart $cart, RequestInterface $request, Product $product, Configurable $configurableproduct)
    {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->configurableproduct = $configurableproduct;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $postValues = $this->request->getPostValue();
        $productId = $postValues['product'];
        $addProduct = $this->product->load($productId);
        if ($addProduct->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) 
        {
            $attributes = $postValues['super_attribute'];
            $simple_product = $this->configurableproduct->getProductByAttributes($attributes, $addProduct);
        }
    }
}
```